Conditional plotting with table & convexhull
Giving these data (datos.txt)
0   23      -0.3    26/11/2023 14:45:00
0   23.1    -0.3    26/11/2023 13:45:00
0   23.2     0      11/02/2023 18:15:00
0   24      -0.6    26/11/2023 15:15:00
0   25      -0.2    26/11/2023 13:15:00
0   26       0      11/02/2023 11:15:00
0   27      -0.3    26/11/2023 16:15:00
0   28      -0.1    26/11/2023 12:45:00
0   29       0      11/02/2023 10:45:00
0   30      -0.2    30/10/2022 16:15:00
0   32       0      12/02/2023 18:15:00
0   32.1    -0.3    26/11/2023 11:45:00
0   33      -0.7    18/12/2023 13:15:00
0   34       0.1    12/06/2022 08:15:00
0   34.1     0.6    30/10/2022 16:45:00
0   34.2     0.3    12/05/2024 21:45:00
0   36      -0.3    26/11/2023 11:15:00
0   37      -0.5    28/01/2024 11:45:00
0   37.1    -0.4    22/01/2024 11:15:00
0   37.2    -0.2    31/10/2022 15:45:00
0   37.3    -0.3    12/01/2024 03:45:00
0   37.4    -0.5    18/12/2023 12:45:00
0   38      -0.7    29/10/2022 12:15:00
0   38.1    -0.2    22/03/2024 20:15:00
0   39      -1.4    19/12/2023 15:45:00
0   39.1     0.3    29/03/2023 09:45:00

and this script
reset session
set table $HULL                                                                                
plot "datos.txt" u (gprintf("%.1f",$1)):(($3)>0.2 && ($3)<0.7 ? (gprintf("%.f",$2)): NaN) w table convexhull                     
unset table                                                                                
print $HULL

I obtain the following result
0.0      nan
0.0      nan
0.0      nan
0.0      nan
0.0      nan
0.0      nan
0.0      nan
0.0      nan
0.0      nan
0.0      nan
0.0      nan
0.0      nan
0.0      nan
0.0      nan
0.0     34
0.0     34
0.0      nan
0.0      nan
0.0      nan
0.0      nan
0.0      nan
0.0      nan
0.0      nan
0.0      nan
0.0      nan
0.0     39

Is there a way to dump only the non-nan rows into the $HULL file ?
without table it is possible but then I'm not allowed to use explicit format for x & y columns.

As I understand your question, you want to plot a convex hull, but only from a set of filtered points (depending on a 3rd column) and get the x,y data in a custom format into a table.
Although, Ethan basically answered your question and already mentioned that you need to do it in two passes, let me give an illustrative example.
The options convexhull and if and with table do not work together.
Hence:

combine convexhull together with a ternary filter in the y-column (not using table and if options)

The data in $HULL in the example below will look like this:
# Curve 0 of 1, 10 points
# x y type
-1.726 -0.494  i
-1.192 1.257  i
-0.493 1.711  i
1.982 0.274  i
2.456 -0.273  i
0.811 -1.694  i
-0.208 -2.535  i
-0.604 -2.391  i
-1.014 -1.824  i
-1.726 -0.494  i

If you are not happy with the headers and the extra i column, get the desired format into $HULL2 via sprintf() and with table by adding the lines:
set table $HULL2
    plot $HULL u (sprintf("%.3f %.3f", $1, $2)) w table
unset table
print $HULL2

And $HULL2 will look like this:
-1.726 -0.494
-1.192 1.257
-0.493 1.711
1.982 0.274
2.456 -0.273
0.811 -1.694
-0.208 -2.535
-0.604 -2.391
-1.014 -1.824
-1.726 -0.494

In order to illustrate:

The convexhull will be created only from the "green" points where the values of column 3 are inbetween cmin=0.2 and cmax=0.7.
the table $HULL2 contains the data in the desired format (here: "%.3f")

Script: (requires gnuplot>=6.0.0, because of convexhull)
### create custom formatted table of convex hull of filtered datapoints
reset session

# create some random test data
set table $Data
    plot '+' u (invnorm(rand(0))):(invnorm(rand(0))):(rand(0)) w table
unset table

set offsets 0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1
set key noautotitle

cmin = 0.2
cmax = 0.7
set palette defined (0 "red", cmin "red", cmin "green", cmax "green", cmax "red", 1.0 "red")

set table $HULL
    set format x "%.3f"
    set format y "%.3f"
    plot $Data u 1:(($3>cmin && $3<cmax) ? $2 : NaN) convexhull
unset table
print $HULL

set table $HULL2
    plot $HULL u (sprintf("%.3f %.3f", $1, $2)) w table
unset table
print $HULL2

set format x "%h"   # restore default in case you changed it above
set format y "%h"

plot $HULL u 1:2 w lp pt 6 ps 2 pi -1 lc "black", \
     $Data u 1:2:3 w p pt 7 lc palette z
### end of script

Result:


This form of the plot with table command will skip any lines that don't match the "if" condition
gnuplot> set table
gnuplot> plot "datos.txt" u (gprintf("%.1f",$1)) : (gprintf("%.f",$2)) \
      with table if (($3)>0.2 && ($3)<0.7)
0.0     34
0.0     34
0.0     39

However with table does not know anything about filter or smoothing operations so you cannot use convexhull here.
You could do this in two passes, however.  One pass to select the hull points and a second pass to print them in the desired format:
set table $TEMP
plot "datos.txt" convexhull with points
unset table

set table $HULL
plot $TEMP u (gprintf("%.1f",$1)) : (gprintf("%.f",$2)) with table
unset table

I am not sure that it makes any sense to filter the y value of points in a hull set, but if you explain in more detail what you are trying to do maybe that will become clear.

It's a good answer: Now I know that convexhull cannot be used with table, and that, without table, I can use it but I cannot use explicit format. In that case, I can just define the appropriate format first with set format x and set format y, then plot and finally redefine the x & y format for other uses if necessary (if the format definition is made within the set table block, then format redefinition is not even necessary at least for retrieving the former tics format). To filter the y value will be useful for a much more complex case, not certainly for this simple one.

.@Ethan In my previous comment I told you that, without table, I can use convexhull in  conditional plotting (that is, plot... if...) provided that I don't impose a given data format. So I have just tried, for a 4-column file, plot file u 1:2 convexhull if(($4)>vii && ($4)<=vff) but this gave me an error too. Does that mean that even without an explicit format, convexhull cannot be used in a conditional plot ?

The use of "plot ... if ()" for most plot styles is present in the gnuplot development version (6.1) but not yet in 6.0.   Version 6.0 only recognizes it for "with table".
